# Azure AD Multi Tenant Authentication - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I have followed **[This](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/)** tutorial to create a sample app that authenticates using Azure AD. However, I have changed multiple things since I wanted to implement it for multi-tenant. 
I did the following things different from the tutorial:

1. Used **'common'** as the tenant in web.config
2. Used **'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/'** as an aad instance on web.config

The app works fine. I am redirected to the URL above for logging and redirected back as well.
But the user context is still blank. (ie. Request.IsAuthenticated / User.IsAuthenticated is blank even after user is successfully authenticated)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you disable issuer validation?

Comment: Thanks @juunas. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Seems in this case the authentication was failing in issuer validation.
In applications that allow any tenant to sign in, disabling issuer validation is an okay choice.

If you do want to limit the tenants that can sign in, don't disable it.
Instead you would need to implement custom issuer validation.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work. Also, now once the user is signed in using the method above, how can I call GRAPH API, without him requiring to log in manually again?

Comment: Usually you would setup an event listener in the authentication configuration, which would be executed when an authorization code is received. You can then use MSAL to exchange the authorization code for tokens for the Graph API.

Comment: Could you please point out to a definitive tutorial or sample. That would be of great help since I am quite new to this.

Comment: I found this one: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2. Especially this part will interest you: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2/blob/master/GroupManager/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs